# Benchmark player pro vs Mathematica

Tags: system-performance

I have a new Computer (Thinkstation: Intel Xeon E5-2630 v3 (2.4 GHz x 16) and want to compare its Performance against two others (Dell: Xeon X5560 2.9GHz x 8, Tri: i7-4790 3.6Ghz x 8). On first two Mathematica 11.0 is installed. On last Player pro 11 is installed. If I use Mathematica BenchmarkReport with 8 Kernels started (LaunchKernels[8]) the Tri PC only gets a Rating 2.25 vs. Dell 4.18 and Thinkstation 5.38. It makes no sense to me from the clock Speed of the CPUs. So the question is if Player pro does Benchmark differently? Can someone confirm or test?

Remark: If I use LaunchKernels[4] instead of 8 the results are: Tri: 1.98; Dell: 2.74; ThinkStation: 3.63. Again the Tri is way off. Without Multi threading it is: Tri: 1.48; Dell: 0.92; ThinkStation: 1.4.

Comment: except for the allowed number of parallel kernels I think it is pretty much the same code, so I would be surprised very much when the Benchmark would be done differently. On my laptop the benchmark with Mathematica 10.4.1 gives 0.7 vs. 0.73 on PlayerPro 10.4.1 which seems within the expected uncertainty. Have you any indication that the benchmark results are really that surprising? I could well imagine that for such a parallel benchmark the Xeon processors are that much faster than the i7 despite the (max.) clock speed (e.g. due to memory bandwidth, cache sizes, ...)

Comment: @Albert: If you check any CPU comparison the Xeon X5560 has a far poorer Rating for Geekbench 3 multicore compared to the i7-4790. The only think beeing obviously different is the Player pro licence. But thanks to your confirmation that does not seem to be issue. I also expect that the code for the Player pro is the same. It seems that the Tri PC has an issue then. As I am looking for a new CPU I Need to understand why it is so slow to avoid a pitfall.

Comment: What OS do you run on each of them? Are you sure the general setup is correct? Have you tried other (non-mathematica) benchmarks, especially some that test parallel execution? I have not much experience, but matching published benchmark results seems to be an art in itself :-)

Comment: Dell, Tri: win7, Thinkstation: Win10, So it is all Windows. Do you expert difference There?

Comment: between different windows versions? not really, but I can't exclude either.  I think having some non-mathematica (but parallel) benchmark results for the three machines would probably be most helpful to decide what the issue could be, but is it turns out to not be mathematica specific that would then most probably be off-topic for this site. What about other differences between the machines, like amount of memory, ssd vs. hd and such?

Comment: I would agree that, with the results given by you, anything else would be off Topic.

Comment: A very quick search for the two processors give some more information which I think could well explain the differences: i7-4790 has 8MB cache and 5 GT/s bus speed,  the Xeon E5-2630 v3 has 20MB cache and 8 GT/s bus speed. But first of all the i7 has 4 real cores (8 threads) only compared to 8 real cores (16 threads) for the Xeon. All of these should make the Xeon perform better with more Kernels which is what you see in your benchmarks. While I don't know whether these differences alone can really explain the values you have seen I would not be surprised if they would...

Comment: Usually we disable multi threading for the computer. But it is worth checking if the Tri only has one CPU installed (all others have two installed) and still runs on multi-threading.